# How to report Code Coverage metrics across git repositories?

Tags: azure-devops, teamcity, code-coverage

We are using private git repositories in Azure DevOps and I have a requirement to create code coverage report across git repositories. Our build CI/CD pipelines are using both [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) & [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/devops).
I have looked at options and there is no straightforward solution to this problem. I am thinking about the following options:

- using service like [coveralls.io](https://coveralls.io/features), there is an option to add private repositories; the drawback it is subscription based service
- using [TeamCity SonarQube plugin](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/SonarQube+plugin); It is not ideal and limited to the plugin features; I haven't tried it yet.
- using custom script to query and aggregate existing code coverage metrics of last successful build in TeamCity/Azure DevOps across projects and group them by repository; Both [Azure DevOps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1) & [TeamCity](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API) offer REST APIs that can be used to get the data.

I still need a solution for Azure DevOps builds, however I have to admit I have not researched this properly yet.

**Has anyone done cross repository code coverage reporting and what approach/tools might be best**?

Answer (score 3):

If you use python and GitLab like I do, you can include a test coverage report in your CI/CD pipeline. You `pip install coverage` and then just run `coverage` in your pipeline. The following is an excerpt from an AWS lambda pipeline, but you should be able to find something similar for your environment:

```
 script:
    - pip install -r ./awslambda/requirements.txt
    - coverage run -m unittest discover -v -s "./awslambda" -p "*_test.py"
    - coverage report
```

The above generates a nice code coverage report and it is free of charge, for Python, AWS and GitLab.

Comment: Thanks, however I need to implement something similar in Azure DevOps builds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sonarqube. It does not generate its own test coverage report, but re-uses the coverage file of your existing pipelines.